# Grouping item with title in toolbar item menu

Tags: android, android-studio, grouping, android-toolbar, menuitem

I wanna grouping this following items, this is a toolbar item menu pic 1 . I want to change it, like below : pic 2 the last one. so what should i do ? please help me. Thanks

This is my xml code : 
`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_city"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_black_24dp"
    android:title="filter"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="true">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/cityAll"
            android:title="SEMUA" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/citySby"
            android:title="SURABAYA" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/cityJkt"
            android:title="JAKARTA" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/statusAll"
            android:title="SEMUA STATUS" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/statusPublish"
            android:title="PUBLISH" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/statusNotPublish"
            android:title="NOT PUBLISH" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/statusClose"
            android:title="CLOSE" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

`

[image: pic 1][image: pic 2]

Comment: may this help you 
https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-how-to-group-menu-items.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity">  

<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search2"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        myapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="false"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/filter_city"
        android:title="City"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_black_24dp"
        android:title="filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/cityAll"
                android:title="SEMUA" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/citySby"
                android:title="SURABAYA" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/cityJkt"
                android:title="JAKARTA" />

     </menu>
     </item>

       <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search2"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        myapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="General"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="false"/>
           <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/statusAll"
                android:title="SEMUA STATUS" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/statusPublish"
                android:title="PUBLISH" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/statusNotPublish"
                android:title="NOT PUBLISH" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/statusClose"
                android:title="CLOSE" />
          </menu>
    </item>
</item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution try this snippet -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cityAll"
        android:title="SEMUA" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/citySby"
        android:title="SURABAYA" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cityJkt"
        android:title="JAKARTA" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statusAll"
        android:title="SEMUA STATUS" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statusPublish"
        android:title="PUBLISH" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statusNotPublish"
        android:title="NOT PUBLISH" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statusClose"
        android:title="CLOSE" />

</menu>
```

**Here is your output -**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer and edited my question Al-Amin, but i think it's not answer of my question.. anyway thank you